# How to get ffmpeg to run on Heroku? (libpulsecommon-15.99.so error)

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg

I'm trying to **run ffmpeg on Heroku using an Aptfile** (for use in a Flask app where I want to be able to **perform audio conversions using pydub**, which works fine locally.)

```
# Aptfile
libsndfile1
libsndfile1-dev
ffmpeg
libvpx7
libpulse0
pulseaudio
```

I've got these buildpacks:

```
# Output from `heroku buildpacks`
1. heroku-community/apt
2. heroku/python
```

And I keep getting this error with a simple `heroku run 'ffmpeg --version'`:

> ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-15.99.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is on Heroku-22, but I was getting the same error on Heroku-20.

Now I've spent hours on this and I'm still confused as to...

1. What is `libpulsecommon-15.99.so` even part of?
2. Is it a case of the library not being installed? Or being installed but not found?

- `ls $HOME/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libpulse` (where `$HOME` is `/app/`) gives:

```
libpulse-simple.so.0
libpulse-simple.so.0.1.1
libpulse.so.0
libpulse.so.0.24.1
```

- `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns `/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/app/.apt/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/app/.apt/usr/lib:`

I'm lost and these are hours of my life I'm not going to get back

---

I'm also wondering if there's much a point trying to get ffmpeg to work on Heroku this way: with the dependencies listed above (in the Aptfile), I'm already at 487 MB in slug size (out of a 300 MB soft limit, 500 MB hard limit), for a codebase under 1 MB.

Any help welcome. I'll update the question as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `libpulsecommon-15.99.so` even part of?

On Ubuntu 22.04, [upon which the Heroku 22 stack is based](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#stack-support-details), [it is part of the `libpulse0` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libpulsecommon-15.99.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) that you have already included in your `Aptfile`. I'm not sure why it isn't being found at runtime.

Instead of installing via Ubuntu packages, you might try a dedicated FFmpeg buildpack. [This one](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest) looks pretty popular.

Something like this should do it:

1. `heroku buildpacks:remove heroku-community/apt`
2. `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git`
3. `git rm Aptfile`
4. `git commit`

Comment: This solution works for both pyav and python-ffmpeg. Waay better than using an aptfile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pulseaudio - and a few other packages - install libraries in subdirectories of wherever you have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so the libraries aren't in the path. You'll need to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to handle those subdirectories.

Something like this will help:

```bash
# list the directories
ls -lah -d `$HOME/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*/

# add each to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# make sure to add each one as necessary, I only show off one path below
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/"

# check that it worked
ffmpeg --help
```